# Saving ANT build results and displaying at end of batch run

Tags: batch-file, ant, build

I wrote a batch file that runs multiple ant builds sequentially. I am wondering if there is a way I can save the results of each build (whether it succeeded or failed) and display it at the end? For example:

```
Project1 - Success
Project2 - Success
Project3 - Failed
Project4 - Success
```

I cannot edit any of the ant build files, only the batch file I use to run them:

```
@echo off
cd c:\<project1_dir>\build
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build1.xml
echo.
cd c:\<project2_dir>\build
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build2.xml
echo.
cd c:\<project3_dir>\build\
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build3.xml
echo.
cd c:\<project4_dir>\build
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build4.xml
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

Based on David W's answer, I came up with the following:

```
@echo off
cd c:\<project1_dir>\build
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build1.xml
set result1=%ErrorLevel%
echo.
cd c:\<project2_dir>\build
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build2.xml
set result2=%ErrorLevel%
echo.
cd c:\<project3_dir>\build\
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build3.xml
set result3=%ErrorLevel%
echo.
cd c:\<project4_dir>\build
call C:\Home\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant -buildfile build4.xml
set result4=%ErrorLevel%

if "%result1%"=="0" (
    echo Project1: Succeeded
) else (
    echo Project1: Failed
)
if "%result2%"=="0" (
    echo Project2: Succeeded
) else (
    echo Project2: Failed
)
if "%result3%"=="0" (
    echo Project3: Succeeded
) else (
    echo Project3: Failed
)
if "%result4%"=="0" (
    echo Project4: Succeeded
) else (
    echo Project4: Failed
)
```

The above code does exactly what I wanted it to do. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant returns an exit code of `0` on good builds and an exit code of non-zero on bad builds. This is stored in `errorLevel` and can be tested with an `if` statement:

```
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo "Job Failed"
)
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
   echo "Job Succeeded
)
```

Or something like that... I'm not really up on my Windows Batch file syntax. I don't know how `call` affects the setting of `ErrorLevel`. You may have to set an environment variable to `ErrorLevel` in the called script, and then work from there.

Take a look at using a Continuous Build System like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) which will automate a lot of these issues for you. Jenkins can build:

- At a particular time.
- When source code is changed.
- On demand
- Or a combination of the above (Build at 5pm everyday, but only if the source code was changed).

This will move builds to an independent server (no more, *It works on my machine* issues), and Jenkins will keep the build output, show which jobs succeeded or failed on its dashboard, and even email (or tweet or IM) particular people (including the culprit) when a build fails. If you use unit tests, Jenkins can run the unit tests, and show you how many of those tests succeeded or failed.

Jenkins uses Java, but it's fairly easy to setup -- even on a Windows system. It can use Tomcat or JBoss as an application server engine, or it's own internal application server.

Comment: I have used Jenkins for my Java projects, but this is just a tool I use in Eclipse to build my whole workspace. I do it this way to make sure each project builds in a specific order, since some projects rely on others, which need to be built first. Is "errorlevel" built-in, or is that a variable I need to create/set manually? I know there's a way to mimic arrays in batch files, so I may add the results of each call to that, if I can retrieve the result after using the "call" statement

Comment: I was definitely over-complicating this. I have it working now, based on your answer. I'll post an update in my original question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Errorlevel is both an environment variable and a `builtin` in Batch. If you say `if ErrorLevel 1`, it checks for an exit code 1 or higher. If you say `%ErrorLevel% EQ 2` it is exactly 2. That's why you can't do `if ErrorLevel 0`. At least if I remember my Batch programming correctly.

Comment: From what I've seen, you're absolutely right. I edited my original post to show the successful code, based on your answer. Thanks a bunch!